# Org mode: how to display tree content only via Elisp

Tags: org-mode

I'm new to Elisp and I'd like to start using Emacs org Mode as my main writing tool. For that to happen I'm trying to set up a good configuration with custom functions. What I'm trying to achieve is "display the org document as content only". When I press SHIFT+TAB in Org mode, the buffer cycles between "Overview", "Content" and "Show All". I found that I could switch to "Overview" using command `org-overview`, but I can't find how to activate "Content" or "Show All" using Elisp.

**EDIT:**
Here is the different style of one simple org document. What I want to find is what commands could swap my document state to "Content" or "Show All":

Overview:
[image]

Content:
[image]

Show All:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the command `outline-show-all`.

The doc of that command is:

> `outline-show-all` is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `outline.el`.
>
> It is bound to `<menu-bar> <Org> <Show/Hide> <Show All>`.
>
> `(outline-show-all)`
>
> Show all of the text in the buffer.

You can easily find that information by pressing <kbd>C-h k</kbd> (bound to the command `describe-key`) and  clicking on the menu item `Org` → `Show/Hide` → `Show All`.

---

You get the table of contents with the command `org-content`:

> `org-content` is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `org.el`.
>
> `(org-content &optional ARG)`
>
> For more information check the manuals.
>
> Show all headlines in the buffer, like a table of contents.
>   With numerical argument N, show content up to level N.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. What about the "content" view?

Comment: @lvictorino Sorry, my bad. The visibility level [`CONTENTS`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Global-and-local-cycling.html#Global-and-local-cycling) is clearly defined in the manual. I added a note about the command `org-content`.

Comment: no worries <3 thanks a lot!

Comment: (and thanks for showing me `C-h k`! It'll be useful.